# Using [ValidateScript] in Param results in error about already declared parameter

Tags: powershell, param

I have the following Param block at the start of my script:

```
Param
(
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [ValidateScript({Test-Path $_ -PathType Leaf})]
    [string]$Config,

    [switch]$OverThresholdOnly,
    [switch]$SendEmail,
    [switch]$Debug
)
```

When I run the script I get the error:

```
"A parameter with the name 'Debug' was defined multiple times for this command. At line:1 char:1"

Line:1 and char:1 is the start of the Param block.
```

If I change the $Debug to $Verbose I get the same error about Verbose. I've tried putting the $debug at the top of the Param block with the same error.

If I remove the [ValidateScript] section it works fine.

Can anybody tell me why it does this? Why [ValidateScript] is using $Debug and how to get around this short of renaming the variable?

Answer (score 4):

PowerShell has ubiquitous parameters which exist for every cmdlet.

Check out `get-help about_common_parameters` or click [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd315352.aspx).

`-Debug` and `-Verbose` are two of the common parameters. Chose a different name to avoid the naming collision.

When you add the parameter attribute it changes the way PowerShell treats the parameters. It becomes an advanced function at that point a.k.a a script cmdlet. Script cmdlets receive the common parameters automatically.

Check out `get-help about_Functions_Advanced` or click [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd315326.aspx)

And `get-help about_Functions_Advanced_Parameters` or click [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347600.aspx)

Comment: I was using the parameters because they were common. Stick to a common set to make life easier. I also checked they were not reserved.

Even though the $Debug parameter is not being validated by the [ValidateScript] it still stops me from using the Debug parameter in my own script?

Comment: @Pauby Did you see what I wrote? When you add the parameter attribute `[Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]` PowerShell automatically adds the common parameters so that's why you are getting a naming collision.